# jquery notation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm busy debugging someone else's code and I've come across something I think is odd.

I have two PHP pages, each of which imports a script containing a bunch of general functions. One of these functions is called `getFormTableOptions`.

Each of the two pages draws a slightly different form. Some of the fields are exactly the same. On both pages there's a select box with the `onchange` event:

```
$('#form_table_name').php('getFormTableOptions', this.value, 'false', this.form.data_source.value)
```

My question is: what are the possible reasons why the `onchange` event would trigger fine in one page and on the other tell me that:

```
PHP function "makeFormReportGroup" does not exist in the specified file!
```

If this is a basic question please have patience, I'm very new to jQuery and I'm really struggling to find references to this syntax.

Comment: What the heck is `$('#form_table_name').php(`?

Comment: Does "makeFormReportGroup" exist in the file you're having issues with?

Comment: You're comparing *apples* and *oranges*. JavaScript (jQuery) and PHP are two separate technologies.

Comment: It looks like you are using some kind of special library. `$('#form_table_name').php()` is not part of the jQuery API. I don't even understand if your code is executed on the server (using jQuery-PHP?) or in the browser. Please make clear what technologies you are using here.

Comment: oh come on, my question was effectively "What the heck is $('#form_table_name').php?". Why does Rocket get upvoted when I get downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jQuery.php` plugin file is included on one page, but not the other.

Comment: @Rocket I assume there's a jquery php plugin that's being used somewhere